# What is the direct link for the standalone Java EE JAR file?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar

Where can I obtain the standalone Java EE JAR file? I've looked everywhere on sun.com, but can't find a way to get the JAR file without also installing the app server, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked too and didn't find one. Possibly there simply ain't.

Go on, bite the bullet, download the app server. You're going to need one sooner or later anyway, right?

Otherwise, if you already have an app server... then you should already have the jar too.

Comment: (but I did download the thing standalone before!)

Answer (score 3):

You could download it from a Maven repository:

- for Java EE 5: http://download.java.net/maven/1/javaee/jars/
- for Java EE 6: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/javax/javaee-api/6.0/

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you looking for? You do need an app server that implements the Java EE 6 API, such as Glassfish v3. Just having a JAR file with the Java EE API without any implementation isn't useful.

Answer (score 2):

Java EE is a collection of specifications:

- Servlet
- JMS
- EJB
- etc.

You can get the individual implementation jars for the apache geronimo server from the central maven repository under

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/geronimo/specs/